# Problem Setting up Slash Commands on Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I was working on Slash Commands and everything went well until i turned the bot on and the bot turns on but i get this error: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\frank\OneDrive\Desktop\kiki\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:753:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\frank\OneDrive\Desktop\kiki\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:565:14)
at async REST.request (C:\Users\frank\OneDrive\Desktop\kiki\node_modules@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:999:22)
at async C:\Users\frank\OneDrive\Desktop\kiki\src\functions\handleCommands.js:34:11 {
rawError: {
code: 50035,
errors: { '0': [Object] },
message: 'Invalid Form Body'
},
code: 50035,
status: 400,
method: 'PUT',
url: 'https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/994028254191169636/guilds/994028059579662417/commands',
requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Function: toJSON] ] }
}

heres my code for the command handler:

```
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require("fs")



const clientId = '994028254191169636';
const guildId = '994028059579662417';



module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async(commandFolders, path) => {
        client.commandArray = []
        for(folder of commandFolders){
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);

                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                client.commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON)
            }
        
        }
        
        const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.token);

        (async () => {
            try {
                console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

                await rest.put(
                    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
                    { body: client.commandArray },
                );

                console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
            } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            }
        })();

    };
};

Please help me resolve this soon thanks :)
```

Comment: helllo could someone please help me thx :)

Comment: Can you include an example of one of your commands